# Visualforce Input Field for Decimals

Tags: visualforce

Is there a way to put a decimal field on a visualforce page and allow the user to update it?

I'm able to display as OutputText per below but I would like the user to be able to change.

```
  <apex:OutputText value="{0, number, 00.00}" Label="CMS%">
  <apex:param value="{!Applicant__c.CMSP__c}" />
   </apex:OutputText>
```

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Does the regular apex:inputField not meet your needs?

Comment: or outputField with inLineEdit enabled?

Comment: OK - That was odd.  Yes the apex:inputField works.  There was some other issue that was causing it not to work.  I started over with a new page and stripped it down to just the core.  Now I'll add back in the rest to see what happens.